# In App Purchase frequency of In App Notify

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

In my application, I am selling images. My program flow is as follows:
    1. Buy Button : performs the purchase
    2. On getting the signed data and signature, I sent it to my server to get it verified
    3. If verified, my server responds with the URLS of the images that are sold
    4. I store them in a database and then sends confirm notification

My question is, If due to some network issues, steps 2 & 3 fails. So I will not be confirming the notification. In that case, how often will i get the IN APP NOTIFY. Will google send the signed data and signature again or will I have to store them as soon as i get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my own testing, the first one came after 2 minutes, the second one came after 15 minutes. And i do not have the patient to wait for the third one.

Comment: I too was able to get the second In_APP_NOTIFY after 5 to 6 mins. But I was not able to get the third one. As per the documentation google should sent it periodically. But its not happening in reality it seems.

Comment: another thing is that if you request another purchase, any previous unconfirmed order will be sent along as well

Comment: I do not receive the subsequent IN_APP_NOTIFY when testing this case.  Can someone confirm that it is also supposed to work with test product id ('android.test.purchased')?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another problem. If we initiate 2 or 3 purchases the same thing happening as CChi said. But have you seen the merchant account... It is not updating if no CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS is sent for earlier order. (ie. Charged and Shipped are not green).

Please let me know if anybody found fix regarding that.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply.. the issue is not a problem. It's obvious process that needs time to be verified by google and after that they will change the status :)